# Extracting a pattern using sed command

Tags: sed

I have a string like this

```
 "112344 1234234 guest 25 % allocation used"
```

I want to extract `25` out of this string using sed.

In the given line "112344 1234234 guest 25 % allocation used", I am interested in only "25 %". The first fields can be empty also, something like this:

"              25 % allocation used"

but " % allocation used" is fixed string. 
So the regex should be based on this fixed pattern.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: It's hard to come up with regex patterns for extracting something based on only a single sample input. Which parts vary? In what ways? (Which is, of course, the essence of writing the regex in the first place.)

Comment: This is terribly unspecific. You always want the fourth field? The first two-digit number?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want `25` extracted, or `25 %`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 cut -d% -f1 | awk '{ print $(NF) }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want the field that is fourth from the right. To get this, I'd use `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $(NF-3) }'
```

If it absolutely must be in `sed`, try this:

```
sed -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/\(^|.* \)\(.*\) % allocation used/\1/'
```

Comment: It is not extracting 25 %. Instead it is printing the entire line.

Comment: @Fayaz I had used the `\<` metacharacter, which is an extension in GNU sed. I've modified it to work with any POSIX-compliant sed.

Comment: @Fayaz You might want to update your question. It states `I want to extract 25 out of this string using sed.` Use this if you need "%" too - `sed -e 's/.*\<\(.*\) allocation used/\1/`

Comment: @Jaypal Thanks, I'd missed that ambiguity. I'll modify my answer after giving Fayaz a chance to clarify. BTW, yours isn't quite right - it only prints the `%`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I don't think the updated solution would work if the  first few fields are empty and the string starts with `25 % allocation used`

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber LOL! I installed GNU SED on my mac and looks like it is acting up. Worked fine on my system - `[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text5
112344 1234234 guest 25 % allocation used
25 % allocation used
[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed -e 's/.*\<\(.*\) allocation used/\1/' text5
25 %
25 %`

Comment: @Michael, Can you help me further, If I reduce the fixed string to just " %", then how can I extract. I want to keep fixed string to minimum possible.

Comment: @jaypal add a --posix flag to get closer to what Fayaz is using. The `\<` seems not to be feasible; the problem is only when switching the `\<` to a space. I tested with the space, GNU sed makes it easier to get what's desired..

Comment: @Fayaz - if you want absolute minimum, just use the awk solution.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber, I need just 25, % is not needed. Can you please give me the earlier sed command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the number preceding the '%' is 2 digits then you can use the following

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text5
112344 1234234 guest 25 % allocation used
25 % allocation used
2344 guest 15 % allocation used

[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed 's/.*\(.. %\).*/\1/' text5
25 %
25 %
15 %
```